# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo InflateException

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi I'm new to Android programming. here I'm doing simple project of calculating taxi fare according to the distance from current position to the city selected.
But I'm getting error.

This my **map.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Maps" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_distance_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" 
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_distance_time"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

This is my **Maps.java** class

```
package com.example.mainproject;

import com.example.mainproject.R;

import com.example.mainproject.Maps.DownloadTask;

import com.example.mainproject.DirectionsJSONParser;
import com.example.mainproject.Maps.ParserTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Maps extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap map;
    ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
    TextView tvDistanceDuration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

tvDistanceDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_distance_time);

        // Initializing 
        markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
        map = fm.getMap();

        // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);     

        // Setting onclick event listener for the map
        map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                // Already two locations                
                if(markerPoints.size()>1){
                    markerPoints.clear();
                    map.clear();                    
                }

                // Adding new item to the ArrayList
                markerPoints.add(point);                

                // Creating MarkerOptions
                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

                // Setting the position of the marker
                options.position(point);

                /** 
                 * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
                 * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
                 */
                if(markerPoints.size()==1){
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                }else if(markerPoints.size()==2){
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                }


                // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
                map.addMarker(options);

                // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
                if(markerPoints.size() >= 2){                   
                    LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
                    LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);

                    // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                    String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);                

                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                    downloadTask.execute(url);
                }

            }
        });

    }

    private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;      


        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";         

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;


        return url;
    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url 
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url 
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                        sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();

                br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
                iStream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
     }



    // Fetches data from url passed
    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{          

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try{
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;        
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
            super.onPostExecute(result);            

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);

        }       
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    public class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread        
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject; 
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;                     

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);    
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            String distance = "";
            String duration = "";



            if(result.size()<1){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Points", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }


            // Traversing through all the routes
            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                    HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j); 

                    if(j==0){   // Get distance from the list
                        distance = (String)point.get("distance");                       
                        continue;
                    }else if(j==1){ // Get duration from the list
                        duration = (String)point.get("duration");
                        continue;
                    }

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng); 

                    points.add(position);                       
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(2);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);   

            }

            tvDistanceDuration.setText("Distance:"+distance + ", Duration:"+duration);

            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            map.addPolyline(lineOptions);                           
        }           
    }   


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }   


}
```

Here is my LogCat file error..

```
10-29 10:52:00.144: E/AndroidRuntime(1777): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 10:52:00.144: E/AndroidRuntime(1777): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mainproject/com.example.mainproject.Maps}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
10-29 10:52:00.144: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-29 10:52:00.144: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-29 10:52:00.144: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-29 10:52:00.144: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-29 10:52:00.144: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-29 10:52:00.144: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-29 10:52:00.144: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
10-29 10:52:00.144: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 10:52:00.144: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-29 10:52:00.144: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-29 10:52:00.144: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-29 10:52:00.144: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-29 10:52:00.144: E/AndroidRuntime(1777): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
10-29 10:52:00.144: E/AndroidRuntime(1777):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
```

Please help me with this and also suggest code for current location and gps tracker..

Comment: Please post full stacktrace, including the nested "caused by" exceptions.